# Brouwer's fixed point theorem in an infinite-dimensional space

Tags: convex-analysis, compactness, fixed-point-theorems

I am wondering if the Brouwer's fixed point theorem can also be applied in an infinite-dimensional space.

For example let $E = [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \times   [0, 1] \times \dots$ be an infinite dimensional space. Let
$f$ be a mapping from $E$ into itself such that for any $x \in E$, 
$$f(x) = (f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x), \dots).$$

For any $k = 1, 2, \dots$, I know that $f_k$ is continuous.

Can I say that $E$ is compact and convex and apply the Brouwer's fixed point theorem; ie $f(x) = x$ has a least one solution?

If yes can you give me a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brouwer fixed point theorem will not be directly applicable, but some generalisation of it is, in this case the [Schauder fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_fixed-point_theorem). By viewing the set as a compact subspace of the Hausdorff topological vector space $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ (with the product topology), this theorem guarantees the existence of a fixed point.